# ng-change in directive is updating the controller's model later then callback method is called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

I have `ng-model` / `ng-change` inside directives. They are 'mapped' to the controllers scope through the attributes. But when the `ng-change` is executed, controller's scope is not updated yet. It kind of lags by one step all the time.

Why does this happen and what is a recommended way to make it in sync?So calling 'change' from directive should call 'do' on the controller and the value value of the scope.params.v should be up to date?

[Example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/s1c05YCYDoueQTbVDucR?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-click` instead of `ng-change` in my-customer-iso.html

refer [this](http://dottedsquirrel.com/blog/angular-js-the-difference-between-ng-click-and-ng-change/)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It wouldn't update parent scope as well